# Sed + how to set parameters in sed command in order to display lines from text file

Tags: linux, sed, awk, ksh

I find the following way to print line from file

In this example we want to print the first line from the hosts file

```
sed -n '1,1p'  /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
```

But how to do the same with parameters inside the sed command

For example

```
Line_number=1
sed -n ' $Line_number,$Line_numberp'  /etc/hosts
 sed: -e expression #1, char 4: extra characters after command
```

what is wrong in my sed syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your shell expand the variable by using " instead of '.

Example:

```
victor@pyfg:~$ line_number=2
victor@pyfg:~$ sed -n "${line_number},${line_number}p" /etc/hosts
1.2.3.4 row-2
```

Since you're only printing a single row, you can just to it like this also:

```
victor@pyfg:~$ sed -n "${line_number}p" /etc/hosts
1.2.3.4 row-2
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun, an awk solution:

```
awk -v line=2 'FNR==line' /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best in your example case to have sed `q`uit the input file once you've found printed the data you desire. For instance:

```
sed 1q <INPUT
```

That will autoprint the first line and then end the process altogether. You can also do:

```
head -n1 <INPUT
```

...to achieve the same effect.

`sed` also interprets `address,ranges` though, and these can be `/regex/,/addresses/` or combinations of the two types as well. For instance:

```
sed '9q;/LINE[0-9]/,/^$/!d' <<FILE
$(printf 'LINE %s\nLINE%s\nLINE %s\\nNOT LINE %s\n\n' $(seq 32))
FILE

###OUTPUT###

LINE2
LINE 3\nNOT LINE 4

LINE6
LINE 7\nNOT LINE 8

LINE 9
```

In the above example `sed` `d`eletes any line it encounters that does `!`not occur between a line containing the string `LINE` immediately followed by `[0-9]` - or any numeric character - and a line not containing `/^$/` any characters at all - or a blank line. In this way lines 1 and 5 - or`LINE [15]` are removed from its output. Conversely though, `LINE 9` is printed because it is instructed to `q` on 9 so it stops processing its script at that point - which occurs before the filter that would delete it.

As suggested in another answer, handling variable parameters is as simply done as allowing the shell to expand them for you - so you should use "$parameter" in order to do so. It is important to remember though that invalid input will be treated as such. For example, for the same reason:

```
echo "///" | sed 's////g'     
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown option to `s'
```

...neither does:

```
v=/ ;echo "///" | sed "s/$v//g"                                 :(
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown option to `s'
```

The value of each variable must be valid `sed` script and cannot contain its delimiter characters.